# Array vs file, in simple python app

Tags: python, arrays, file

I want to create a name-day calendar but I struggle with a question, what method is preferable

1. Load all the names and dates in an array
2. Create a file and search it every time I want to find what day corresponds to a specific name
3. Other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dict(considering the names are unique):

```
{'name1':'someday', 'name2':'someday',...}
```

with names as key and corresponding days as values.

Dicts provide `O(1)` lookup for any item, while lists have `O(N)` lookup.

Instead of saving the data to text files use modules like [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) which allows you to store python objects. You can later load those objects in memory and use them.

Answer (score 0):

In general, searching a file will be slower because hard drives are slow.  Loading names and dates in your array will generally run faster, so first option will be better than the second.